# Zypper: Show all installable versions of a package

Tags: opensuse, sles, zypper

Unfortunately a rpm (`apache2-utils`) has two sources on one server.

If I try to update it, then I get this message:

```
sle-server# zypper in apache2-utils
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'apache2-utils' is already installed.
There is an update candidate for 'apache2-utils', 
but it comes from a repository with a lower priority. 
Use 'zypper install apache2-utils-2.4.34-175.1.x86_64' to install this candidate.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Now I want to know which versions are installable:

```
sle-server# zypper info apache2-utils
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


Information for package apache2-utils:
--------------------------------------
Repository     : ES standard patch baseline 4Q2018
Name           : apache2-utils                    
Version        : 2.4.23-29.27.2                   
Arch           : x86_64                           
Vendor         : SUSE LLC <https://www.suse.com/> 
Support Level  : unknown                          
Installed Size : 221.6 KiB                        
Installed      : Yes (automatically)              
Status         : up-to-date                       
Source package : apache2-2.4.23-29.27.2.src       
Summary        : Apache 2 utilities               
Description    :                                  
    Utilities provided by the Apache 2 Web Server project which are useful
    to administrators of web servers in general.
```

How can I see all installable versions of this package on the command line (without yast)?

Comment: `sudo zypper search -s apache2`?

Comment: @HBruijn yes, I don't read man pages. I ask my favorite search engine. Is this evil? I don't think so. I answered my own question below. Now the next person who prefers to use a search engine (because it is easier) will find the answer soon. Why should I read the man page and not ask a question? (More general question: Why should I go the hard way, if there is an easier way)

Comment: you might have searched google before.... https://superuser.com/questions/791907/zypper-how-to-list-different-available-versions-of-a-package

Comment: As you can already see in the voting: *"this question does not show any research effort"* (although it is nicely formatted)

Comment: @HBruijn yes, you are right. But why not do it the easy, simple, lazy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zypper se -s apache2-utils
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name          | Type    | Version        | Arch   | Repository                       
--+---------------+---------+----------------+--------+----------------------------------
i | apache2-utils | package | 2.4.23-29.27.2 | x86_64 | ES standard patch baseline 4Q2018
v | apache2-utils | package | 2.4.34-175.1   | x86_64 | SLES_12.3_TBZ-PARIV
```